# UPDATE / INSERT calculated values from 2 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

**SOLVED**

I'm stuck with something and I'm not even sure if it's possible what I'm trying to do.

Basically I want to update (or better yet, right away with the insert) a specific field with a multiplication from the current table AND a value from another table.

This is the query so far :

```
UPDATE Orders

SET Total =    (SELECT p.Price * o.Quantity
                FROM Products p, Orders o
                WHERE p.ProductID = o.ProductID
                AND p.ProductID = 110)

WHERE o.OrderID = 112;
```

The strange thing is, when I run the SELECT part exclusively, it returns a clean integer.

When I delete the 'subquery' and insert this number in it's place, the UPDATE query works fine, however when I try to do it like shown above I get an error

> 'Operation must use an updateable query'

Has anyone ever seen and solved this problem? Any help will be very much appreciated, thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Thanks for the help guys, I had to do some tweaking, but now it works perfectly. I've used the query below : (Just to be clear, it's an .mdb Access database)

```
UPDATE Orders
INNER JOIN Products ON Products.ProductID = Orders.ProductID
SET Orders.Total = Orders.Price * Orders.Quantity
WHERE OrderID = 112;
```

Comment: If this issue has been solved, then what you should do is pick the correct answer. Then we will know the issue is resolved (not adding `SOLVED` in the top of the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the subquery correlated with the outer query:

```
UPDATE Orders
    SET Total = (SELECT p.Price * orders.Quantity
                 FROM Products as p
                 WHERE p.ProductID = 110
                )
    WHERE orders.OrderID = 112;
```

Your version takes `quantity` from the orders for product 110 instead of 112.

EDIT:

You can also express this as a join:

```
UPDATE o
    SET Total = p.Price * orders.Quantity
    FROM Orders o, 
        (SELECT *
         FROM Products as p
         WHERE p.ProductID = 110
        ) as p
    WHERE orders.OrderID = 112;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly join with the said table and perform the updation accordingly like

```
UPDATE Orders
INNER JOIN Products ON Products.ProductID = Orders.ProductID
AND Products.ProductID = 110 
AND Orders.OrderID = 112
SET Total = Products.Price * Orders.Quantity;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be the slightly better option. It is similar to Gordon's query, but uses an explicit JOIN between the Products and the Orders table instead of an implicit cross-join between the tables.

```
UPDATE o
SET Total = p.Price * o.Quantity
FROM Products p
    INNER JOIN Orders o
        ON p.ProductID = o.ProductID
WHERE o.OrderID = 112
    AND p.ProductID = 110
```

Although the result will be the same, this style of writing queries is recommended, as I'm sure Gordon will suggest as well.